# Add microsoft.graph.room via graph explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, graph-explorer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I was looking at the above doc. How do I create a user of type microsoft.graph.room in Azure Active Directory on a demo tenant?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , No Graph API support for Exchange objects and operations

You have to use PowerShell , kindly use - **Set-Place**
please see doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-place?view=exchange-ps

Hope this helps

Thanks